# how to get the value inside first class inside the first div?

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="item">
   <div class="name">
     <input type="text" class="XXX">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="name">
     <input type="text" class="XXX">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
   <div class="name">
     <input type="text" class="XXX">
   </div>
</div>
```

how to get value from text box class="xxx" using :eq() in jquery select ,i am trying something like this $('.item:eq(0).name.XXX').val();

Comment: Does: `$('.XXX:eq(0)').val()` meet your needs?

Comment: only think i want to do is to put space in between thanx to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only need to add is space between item:eq(0),name,XXX

$('.item:eq(0) .name .XXX').val();

Answer (score 2):

You should use space between the selectors:

```
$('.item:eq(0) .name .XXX').val();
```

or:

```
$('.item:eq(0) > .name > .XXX').val()
```

or:

```
$('.item:eq(0)').find('input').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('.item:eq(0) .name .XXX')`.  You need to do it like CSS selectors, which require a space to have the next selector apply to a descendant. Or use `>` for immediate child.